# pulling in an image from another section within a matrix loop

Tags: matrix, loop

I am trying to loop through a matrix to output three blocks but also I want to pull in 3 images from 3 different sections. The images are asset fields in 3 other sections. should i loop through those sections using craft.entries or craft.assests? below is an example of what i have been trying out. thanks in advance for any help

```
{% for block in entry.homeMatrix %}
        {% if block.type == "homeMatrix" %}
                <a class="half-box full-box" href="{{ block.entry.first().url }}">
                    {% for image in craft.assets.kind('image') %}
                    <picture class="box-image">
                        <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
                            <source srcset="{{ entry.lTopBannerImg.first().url('gridImages480X340') }}" media="(min-width: 45em)">
                            <source srcset="{{ entry.lTopBannerImg.first().url('gridImageOdd559X315') }}" media="(min-width: 28.4375em)">
                            <source srcset="{{ entry.lTopBannerImg.first().url('gridImages560X520') }}">
                        <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                        <img alt="{{ entry.lTopBannerImgAltText.first().title }}" srcset="{{ entry.lTopBannerImg.first().url('gridImages480X340') }}">
                    </picture>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="box-bar">
                        <h2>{{ block.url }}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="see-more"><span class="plus">Click to see more information</span></div>

                </a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are the three sections whose asset field you want to pull in Singles, or Channels?

Comment: They are singles :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `{% for image in craft.assets.kind('image') %}` is all about in your code since the `image` variable isn't being used anywhere.

But here's the basic structure on how you could loop through 3 separate Asset fields in 3 different single sections inside of a Matrix block:

```
{% for block in entry.homeMatrix %}
    {% if block.type == "homeMatrix" %}

        {% set firstSingle = craft.entries.section('myFirstSection').first() %}
        {% set secondSingle = craft.entries.section('mySecondSection').first() %}
        {% set thirdSingle = craft.entries.section('myThirdSection').first() %}

        {% if firstSingle.myAssetField|length %}
            {% for image in firstSingle.myAssetField %}
                {{ image.url }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if secondSingle.myAssetField|length %}
            {% for image in secondSingle.myAssetField %}
                {{ image.url }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if thirdSingle.myAssetField|length %}
            {% for image in thirdSingle.myAssetField %}
                {{ image.url }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```